# ajax call to web method on server not save session

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I use an ajax to call an API that in **remote server**.

```
  function LoginUser() {
         $.ajax({

             type: "POST",
             url: "http://myServerName/MyAPI" + "/LoginUser",
             data: "{userName: 'aaa'}"
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",
             crossDomain: true,
             success: function (response) {
                 if (response.d != "") {
                     window.location = "WelcomePage.aspx";
                 }
                 else if (response.d == "") {

                 }

             },
             error: function (response) {
             }
         });
         return false;
     }
```

API:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true) ]
        public static string LoginUser(string userName)
        {

            MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient();
            string userID = client.LoginUser(userName).ToString();
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("userID", userID);
            return userID;
        }
```

The response.d returns the userId but in the welcomePage when I try getting the session I get null

```
 string userId = Session["userID"].toString()
```

If I use the API page in the same solution of the login and welcome page it work perfectly.

Thank for help

Comment: is this typing mistake ? Session["userID"].toStriong()

Comment: yes, iI edit the question

Comment: Where do you access this in static method ?

Comment: in this line: http://myServerName/MyAPI" + "/LoginUser

Comment: I am *almost* positive that you cannot set session from a remote server. `HttpContext.Current` will be different, right? Also if it possible, it could be exploited as a vulnerability easily, right? Not sure.